# Extract value from RStudio manipulate package control

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to extract current value from a slider control in manipulate package? For example:

```
library(manipulate)

xx <- seq(-pi, pi, pi/20)

manipulate(
  plot(xx, sin(par.a*xx)),
  par.a = slider(-3, 3, step=0.01, initial = 1))
```

After playing with the slider I would like to get the value of `par.a` for further calculations without having to look at the control and write it by hand each time.

Comment: Have you posted to RStudio forums?

Comment: No, didn't thought about that at the time of posting.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out myself.

It is possible to do with global variables

```
manipulate(
  {plot(xx, sin(par.a*xx))
  a <<- par.a},
  par.a = slider(-3, 3, step=0.01, initial = 1))
```

Maybe it will be of assistance to somebody.

Comment: Nice thinking there.  Now I wonder if it's possible to create a vector `a` in the global environment such that every update to `par.a` is written to a new element of `a`.   That should keep you busy :-)

Comment: No problem in that. Just declare vector `a <- c()` outside of manipulate and use `a <<- c(a, par.a)` during assignment.